# Scanning a multi digit number when converting infix to Postfix

Tags: java, string, calculator, infix-notation

I wrote the following method to convert an infix expression to a postfix expression. If the commented code is removed, the program will return a valid result given single digit integers;   11 + 2 will result in 1 1 2 + rather than 11 2 +, but 1 + 2 - 3 returns 1 2 + 3 -. In order to include n-digit numbers, I implemented an if-statement which concatenates a space to the postfix string if the adjacent character is NOT a number. However, during execution the following error is produced:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3

Code:

```
public static String postfixConversion(String input) {

            int i;
            String postfix = "";

            Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

            for (i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                    while (input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                            ++i;
                    }

                    if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) { 
                                    postfix += input.charAt(i);

                                    if (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1))) { //EXCEPTION OCCURS
                                           postfix += ' ';
                                    } 
                    }

                    else if (precedenceLevel(input.charAt(i)) != 0) {
                            while ((!stack.isEmpty()) && (precedenceLevel(stack.peek()) >= precedenceLevel(input.charAt(i))) && (stack.peek() != '(')) {
                                    postfix += stack.peek();
                                    postfix += ' ';
                                    stack.pop();
                            }

                            stack.push(input.charAt(i));
                    }

                    else if (input.charAt(i) == '(') {
                            stack.push(input.charAt(i));
                    }

                    else if (input.charAt(i) == ')') {
                            while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') {
                                    postfix += stack.peek();
                                    stack.pop();
                            }

                            stack.pop();
                    }
            }

            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    postfix += stack.peek();
                    postfix += ' ';
            }

            return postfix;

    }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is `precedenceLevel()` method?

Comment: Ah, precedenceLevel() returns the numerical precedence of an operator; precedenceLevel('+') returns 1, precedenceLevel('*') returns 2.

Comment: Please provide a full stacktrace and mark the line at which the exception happens.

Comment: Think what happens when `i` is exactly `input.length() - 1`.

Comment: Even after removing commented code, I didn't get valid result for single digit numbers.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic, if i = input.length() - 1 then input.charAt(i+1) will produce an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1)))
```

To:

```
if (i+1 >= input.length() || !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply! The problem lies in these lines:

```
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                postfix += stack.peek();
                postfix += ' ';
        }
```

Here you use the method `peek()`, which simply looks at the object, which is on the top of the stack, without removing it. Therefore, you fall into an endless loop where you keep adding this element in the `postfix` string and just because this element is never removed from the stack, the stack is never empty, so your condition in the while loop is filled and therefore you can never jump out of the while loop.
Try replacing `peek()` with `pop()` as shown below:

```
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                postfix += stack.pop();
                postfix += ' ';
        }
```